# analytics.js Enhanced ECommerce add to cart not working

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

I am trying to setup EC (Enhanced ECommerce). But it gives me a headache after thousand tries..

For some weird reason it registers sessions, it registers 'show product' but the next step. Add to cart isn't measured. And we have enough order to know that people add products to the cart.

Could you guys please help me out?

```
 (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
                m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','__gaTracker');

        __gaTracker('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X', 'auto');
        __gaTracker('require', 'displayfeatures');
        __gaTracker('require', 'ecommerce');
        __gaTracker('require', 'ec');


        __gaTracker('ec:addProduct', {
            'id': 123456,
            'name': 'Nissan Skyline R32/R33/R34 Hardened Engine Mounts MR',
            'price': '195.00',
            'quantity': 1
        });
        __gaTracker('ec:setAction', 'add');
        __gaTracker('send', 'pageview');
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to make your product ID a string - you currently have it as an integer.  Change to the following:

```
__gaTracker('ec:addProduct', {
    'id': '123456',
    'name': 'Nissan Skyline R32/R33/R34 Hardened Engine Mounts MR',
    'price': '195.00',
    'quantity': 1
});
__gaTracker('ec:setAction', 'add');
__gaTracker('send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: Oh i hope that that's the problem.. Didn't think about that one thanks.. Testing it right now :)

Comment: So i tested it. And damn it worked..
Why did this take me this long xD
Thank you very much sir!

Comment: No worries at all, glad to help.  Please feel free to check out my company at dmpg.co.uk if you need any GA/GTM services - we're GA Partners and general geeks!

Comment: In that case. a quick question. Is it me or is the enhanced Ecommerce documentation quite.. hard to read? It covers a lot of functions etc.. but not at a normal way or normal order.. Kinda annoying :/

Comment: To be honest I find the GA docs exceptionally good, especially when you compare it to the my other specialty, Adobe Analytics. However I have spent the last 10 years in the industry so the concepts are more familiar. What i find the biggest issue is that a 'web developer' (of which I was one) will come along and say to a client "we can do your analytics" thinking its just chucking some code on a page. What they need to understand is the actual concepts behind analytics to enable collection of the right data at the right time and thus produce analysis ready data. code is only 10% of analytics!

Comment: Good luck though, if you need any further help with client work please feel free to contact me and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: Yeah i have to agree. If you understand the concept it is more doable.. And yeah it is way more than chucking some code. haha
And thanks a bunch! When i have any further questions or want outsource it (a big possibility in the future) you will be the first on the list :)